# Course of traveling

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, orientation

A ship is traveling with speed 12km/h in North direction.A wind with speed 9km/h with direction from West to East changes the direction of ship.
a)Find resultant speed (Answer.15km/h in course 36.9°)
b) The sheep need to traveling back to starting point. In which course need to be her orientation?
(Answer 253,7°)

(I think that a) is easy of course just a Pithagoras theorem and definition of tan.but I not have any idea at point b))

Comment: A stupid formulation of the problem by someone completely clueless about what they're talking about. Certainly ships do experience _some_ drift due to a side wind, but it's far, far less than the wind's speed. Why didn't the author put an airplane there is beyond my understanding. Ships just do _NOT_ behave as in this problem, so – with a ship inside – the problem is unsolvable. Math is a language of sciences. It's use is for modelling and explaining the reality, not for lying about it.

Comment: I aggre with you for stupid formulation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a line segment of length $12$ from the origin to $(0, 12)$ to represent the ship's movement (of its own).
Draw a line segment of length $9$ from $(0,12)$ to $(9, 12)$ to represent the wind.

The length of the line segment connecting the origin $(0,0)$ and $(9, 12)$ can be found by the Pythagorean Theorem, as you noticed. This is a right triangle with legs of length $12$ and $9$.

As for the heading/bearing, you have to understand the convention:

- Due North is a bearing of $0^\circ$
- Due East is a bearing of $90^\circ$
- Due South is a bearing of $180^\circ$
- Due West is a bearing of $270^\circ$

---

*Edit:* As you have pointed out, the question is likely asking for what course the ship should set, not what it's actual path will be. So the ship will need to aim for $(-9, 0)$ in order to arrive at the origin. This would result in a right triangle with sides $18$ and $12$.

I meant to add earlier - for all such questions, you should definitely draw a triangle (or two)!

Comment: I have a similar idea, but at the answer was 253,7°.

Comment: Maybe the direction of ship need to be 253,7° and the wind make her to travel along the line with course (180°+51°)=231°.

Comment: Maybe, but it looks that have something more tricky! The idea for point (-9;0) seems that doesn't work.

Comment: . I see that angle formed from ship direction and the ship pass was ≈36.9°.  So to get back we need to form a angle 36.9° with the way the ship has traveling. If we ad 180°+36,9°+36.9°=253.8°≈253.7°. It not looks very logic, but maybe the creators of question have think in this way, non sense question maybe.